# java multi threading executor never shutdown threads

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

Could some one take a look this below program ?.

It is working fine for small process, but not exiting the program after completing large process.

Note: If it is small size query, about 50 records (retrieving and updating), the program is Exiting normally....

The purpose of this program is to get the data from the database, go to cloud to read JSON, validate the data and update the record in database with result.

```
public class ThreadLauncher
{

  public static void main(String args[])
   {
    final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()); // or hardcode a number



    List<Future<Runnable>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Runnable>>();

    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
    {
        Future f = service.submit(new Task(n));
        futures.add(f);
    }

    // wait for all tasks to complete before continuing
    for (Future<Runnable> f : futures)
    {
        try {

            f.get();
            //shut down the executor service so that this thread can exit

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Exiting with InterruptedException : " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println("Exiting with ExecutionException : " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    service.shutdownNow();


    System.out.println("Exiting normally...");

}
}

 final class Task
    implements Runnable
{
private int loopCounter;
private int totalLoops = 5;


public Task(int counter)
{
    this.loopCounter = counter;
}

@Override
public void run()
 {
    try { 
        GCPJSON.getInstance().getGCPDataFromJSON(PRODDataAccess.getInstance().getDataToProcess(loopCounter,totalLoops));

        System.out.println("Task ID : " + this.loopCounter + " performed by " + 
     Thread.currentThread().getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: One of the things you need to understand a little more about how threads are "normally" terminated.  In Java, you can't stop a running thread, all you can do is "interrupt" thread and hope that what ever task is running supports interruption.

Comment: The [JavaDocs for `shutdownNow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) even say as much - *"There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will cancel via Thread.interrupt(), so any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate."*

Comment: as already mentioned, u ll need to understand better the overall 'threading' within the JVM. In your example also , `shutdownNow()` does not add any value as you are already blocking your main thread by calling `future.get()` even though those tasks are not implementing the `Callable` interface, meaning that they will not return anything. Still not clear what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I need to exit the program cleanly after completing the process. Could you please update the code to add Callable ? or point me to a good example ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you call `shutdown` or `shutdownNow` on `executorService` it only try to stop active threads and it will return list of active tasks based on Java documentation:

> Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of
>   waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting
>   execution.
>
> This method does not wait for actively executing tasks to terminate. 
>   Use {awaitTermination} to do that.

As documentation says **you need to call `awaitTermination` to make sure every thread has finished** or this method will kill them at the end of timeout.

**UPDATE:**

If you have no idea about timing estimation you can add following lines to make sure that all threads have been finished successfully.

```
int filesCount = getFileCount();//you know the files count, right?
AtomicInteger finishedFiles = new AtomicInteger(0);
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
    executorService.submit(() -> {
        //do you work
        //at the end of each file process
        finishedFiles.incrementAndGet();
    }
while (finishedFiles.get() < filesCount) { //let's wait until all files have been processed 
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
executorService.shutdown();
executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);//anyway they already should have finished
```

Comment: I cannot use awaitTerminaion as I am not sure how  long it takes. I am going to process, millions of records.  I want the program to figure out and exit cleanly.

Comment: That's the only solution man, you must have some estimation for the process, take the upper bond, for example if you expect 1 file takes maximum 10 minutes to complete, write it as `awaitTermination(numberOfFiles*10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)`

Comment: @user3067524 I've added code sample in case you can't estimate process timing

Comment: @user3067524 in your question, you state your problem is that the program didn't finish. Now you say you don't want to wait until it's finished. So which is it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated code.I have changed it from Future to FutureTask and added few lines items. I am hoping all these 10 tasks run in parallel.

```
List<FutureTask<Runnable>> futures = new ArrayList<FutureTask<Runnable>>();

    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
    {
        FutureTask f = (FutureTask) service.submit(new Task(n));
        futures.add(f);
    }

    // wait for all tasks to complete before continuing
   // for (FutureTask<Runnable> f : futures)
    for (int i=0; i< futures.size(); i++)
    {
       FutureTask f = (FutureTask)futures.get(i) ;
        //System.out.println("Number of futureTasks: " + i);
        try {


            if(!f.isDone()){
                //wait indefinitely for future task to complete
                f.get();
                //System.out.println("FutureTask output="+f.get());
            }else{
                System.out.println("Task number :" + i + "Done.");
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println("Exiting with InterruptedException : " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 //If we come out from the loop, we must have completed all the tasks. e.e. In above case , 10 tasks ( 10 loop submites)
    try {
        if (!service.awaitTermination(10000000, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)) {
            System.out.println("Exiting normally...");
            service.shutdownNow();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(!service.isShutdown()){
        System.exit(0);
    }
```